# Chrome Extension detect button inside extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a simple chrome extension and I need it to change the background color of the selected tab page on clicking a button thats within the extension popup.

```
<button id="btn">Change</button>
```

I have tried this:

```
var b = chrome.extension.getElementById('btn');

b.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: '
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000"
        '
    });
});
```

In the JS file, but it does nothing, what is the problem here?

This is my manifest file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "extension",
    "description": "extension disc",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "extension",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.min.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

Comment: A popup builds up its own DOM, so you can use `var element = document.getElementById('btn')` together with `element.addEventListener()` and `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true})` to get the active tab of the current window

Comment: @devnull69 how do I change that active tabs background color then?

Comment: this will always return undefined. its not part of the extensions api `chrome.extension.getElementById` where did you get that?

Comment: @GEspinha the rest of your code should work, so `chrome.tabs.executeScript` should be fine

Comment: @devnull69 I have the following `var b = chrome.extension.getElementById('btn');

b.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true})
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000"'
    });
});` but it doesn't work

Comment: 'cause you ignored the previous comments ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popup builds up its own DOM, so you can use `var element = document.getElementById('btn')` together with `element.addEventListener()` and `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true})` to get the active tab of the current window

Be sure to provide tab permission in your manifest

Then try this in your popup.js

```
var b = document.getElementById('btn');

b.addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";'
    });
}, false);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand where I should put the `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true})`

Comment: puh this is more difficult than it should be ... chrome.tabs.executeScript will use the active tab of the currentWindow automatically, so no need for `chrome.tabs.query` in the first place

Comment: I have done that but it doesn't work :/ Can you please check my manifest file on the question above?

Comment: Do you call your script after document load? Something like `window.addEventListener('load', function() {...}, false)` or `window.onload = function() {...}` or `$(document).ready(function() {...});`?? If not, you are doing it wrong and the DOM is not ready before you start your script. `document.getElementById()` won't be able to find anything if the DOM is not ready

Comment: It now returns `Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "http://www.google.com". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.`

Comment: Nevermind, I had the wrong permissions in the manifest file. It works :) Thank you very much!!